# How to create EFI when installing secondary OS on a Legacy System?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, ubuntu-18.04

I have Windows 10 installed on my laptop in Legacy mode. I want to install Ubuntu. I shrank the Windows main partition by 150GB and am installing Linux there. During installation, I get this error

[image]

Which redirects me [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766945?fbclid=IwAR1kwKbLL3j-96m67pOvsokw9p-dV02MaSzh7hy6Rl0dKJ1capvk05shVsg). It's apparently already been fixed, but still happen in Asus laptops (like mine).

Now, my partition state is as follows:

- 0.5 GB - Some Windows partition
- 500   GB - Windows 10
- 145   GB - Ubuntu 18.04.1
- 5   GB - Swap
- 10   GB - Windows recovery (?)

How can I install Ubuntu without damaging my Windows installation and having dual boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

First, I created an EFI partition when installing Ubuntu. This was done by creating a 200MB partition for EFI (mount point /boot/efi, flags "boot", Lubuntu tells you how to create this).  Lubuntu got installed on the remaining 144.8GB partition space.

After installing, PC booted directly into Windows. Tried to fiddle with Windoows Boot Manager to add Lubunutu using [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), but to no avail. Eventually, got the Live USB pen and ran a [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

PC then booted directly into Lubuntu. Ran an `os-probe` and Windows was detected, so a simple `update-grub` did the trick. Used [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) to make it memorable and voilá.

[image]